# How do you disable archiving for a table?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase

I would expect to have a `Disable Archiving...` like I do for a featureclass.

But for a table, the Enabled Archiving menu-item is grayed out.

Here's the menu for a table:
[image: Menu on a versioned, archived table]

And here's the menu for a featureclass, which is what I would expect according to the [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00270000004s000000.htm):

[image: Menu on a versioned, archived featureclass]

Is there another way to disable archiving on a table? Or is this a bug?

ArcCatalog 10 SP3 client.  Seeing the issue in both SQL Server/Oracle **SDE**.

Comment: Is the table in an arcsde database? is it versioned?

Comment: Yes, sde and versioned, which I think is required in order to enable archiving in the first place.  So, I've successfully registered as versioned, and successfully enabled archiving.  The _H tables are present.  Now I'm trying to disable archiving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a "Disable Archiving..." button to the toolbar by going into the Customize... options and searching for "archiving" under the Commands tab.

Comment: @jay I thought you had already dragged the command and that it was disabled the whole time. This is clearly step one. Time to delete my answer :)

Comment: No, I wasn't thinking clearly on this one!  I guess I was thinking that the if the menu was working for featureclasses, it would work for tables (the docs state objectclasses).